# how to come up with this identity $\sum\limits_{i=r}^{n-k+r}{i \choose r}{{n-i} \choose {k-r}}={{n+1} \choose {k+1}}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

This identity is used in an exercise. Could you help me understand how I should reason to come up with it? Ideally, from a combinatorial point of view.

Comment: What sums do you know that could be helpful  here?

Comment: @Browning I'm familiar with  some identities based on the Pascal's triangle: row-sum, column-sum, diagonals, absorption and something that resembles this a little bit: Vandermonde convolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alex's answer is on the right track. Take a subset $A$ of $[n+1]=\{1,\ldots, n+1\}$ of size $k+1$. So suppose $A=\{a_1,\ldots,a_{k+1}\}$ with the entries in increasing order. Consider $a_{r+1}$. Let us count all the possible $A$ where $a_{r+1}=i+1$. Then the entries $a_1,\ldots,a_r$ must lie in $\{1,\ldots,i\}$ so there are $\binom{i}{r}$ possibilities. Similarly, $a_{r+2},\ldots,a_{k+1}$ must lie in $i+2,\ldots,n+1$, so there are $\binom{n-i}{k-r}$ possibilities. 
Now sum over all possible choices of $i$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint use Vandermonde's identity after placing $i=n+k-r$ and then writing remaining as same $$\sum {n\choose k}+{m-n\choose r-k}={n\choose k}$$

Answer (score 1):

OnRHS is the number of ways to select k+1 objects out of n+1. Start by splitting this set into two disjoint subsets, so that you select r objects from the first and k-r from the second.

Comment: Why the mismatch between $k$ and $k+1$?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you need to select $k+1$ objects but are only selecting $r$ and $k-r$ (a total of $k$) where does the last one come from?

Comment: I think I patched it. See my answer.